# How to set data-min of input and set message if value is less than min value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set min valu of an input, but message doesn't show. How to show this message if input is required and it's entered less value than min value. 
My code is:

```js
$(".mydiv :input").each(function () {
   var min = $(this).attr('datamin');
   if(min !== undefined && min !== null && min !== false) {
   if(value < min) {
      valid = false;
      $(this).addClass('error');
      $(this).closest('label').addClass('red');
      $(this).closest('label').html('Required min value:' + min);
   } else {
      $(this).removeClass('error');
      $(this).closest('label').removeClass('red');
   }
}
```

```html
 <input datamin='1' class="required" name="order"/>
 <label for="order"><?php echo __('order'); ?><span class="red">*</span><span class="min_value" style="display:none"></span></label>
```

Comment: Check your web console.  You're missing a curly brace `}` at the end.

Comment: No, it's now because of copying the code. It's ok. I think problem is datamin attribute, is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach this to an `change` event, instead of doing it on .each. You also need to set the value (using `.val()`)

Conversion and some more validation around the values too would be good (using `isNaN`)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mydiv input").on('change', function() {
    var min = Number($(this).attr('datamin'));
    var value = Number($(this).val());
    if (min !== undefined && min !== null && min !== false && !isNaN(min)) {
      if (value < min || isNaN(value)) {
        valid = false;
        $(this).addClass('error');
        $(this).closest('label').addClass('red');
        $(this).closest('label').html('Required min value:' + min);
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('error');
        $(this).closest('label').removeClass('red');
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.error, .red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv">
  <input datamin='1' class="required" name="order" />
  <label for="order">
    <?php echo __( 'order'); ?><span class="red">*</span><span class="min_value" style="display:none"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually retrieve the value:

```
var theValue = +$(this).val(); //you're not doing this
//note that + sign attempts to coerce a value (vs. text), but you may try some additional validation
if(theValue < min) {
      valid = false;
      $(this).addClass('error');
      $(this).closest('label').addClass('red');
      $(this).closest('label').html('Required min value:' + min);
   } else {
      $(this).removeClass('error');
      $(this).closest('label').removeClass('red');
   }
}
```

EDIT:  And as @potatopeelings adds, you also need to fire this on `change`.